# Weird behavior with Perl string concatenation

Tags: perl, string-concatenation

I'm working on a pretty simple script, reading a maplist.txt file and using the \n separated map names in it to build a command string - however, I'm getting some unexpected behavior.

My full code:

```
# compiles a map pack from maplist.txt
# for every server.
# Filipe Dobreira <dobreira@gmail.com>
# v1 @ Sept. 2011

use strict;
my @servers = <*>;
foreach my $server (@servers)
{
        # we only want folders:
        next if -f $server;
        print "server: $server\n";

        my $maplist = $server . '/orangebox/cstrike/maplist.txt';
        my $mapdir  = $server . '/orangebox/cstrike/maps';

        print "   maplist: $maplist\n";
        print "   map folder: $mapdir\n";

        # check if the maplist actually exists:
        if(!(-e $maplist))
        {
                print "!!! failed to find $maplist\n";
                next;
        }

        open MAPLIST, "<$maplist";
        foreach my $map (<MAPLIST>)
        {
                chomp($map);
                next if !$map;

                # full path to the map file:
                my $mapfile = "$mapdir/$map.bsp";
                print "$mapfile\n";
        }
}
```

Where I declare `$mapfile`, I expect the result to be something like:

```
zombieescape1/orangebox/cstrike/maps/ze_stargate_escape_v8.bsp
```

However, it seems like the concatenation is being made to the START of the string, and the final result ends up being something like:

```
.bspiescape1/orangebox/cstrike/maps/ze_stargate_escape_v8
```

So the `.bsp` portion is actually being written over the start of the leftmost string. I have very little perl experience, and I can only assume this is me failing to understand some quirk or operator behavior.

Note: I've also tried using `"${mapdir}/${map}.bsp"`, concatenating everything with the dot operator, and a `join "", $mapdir, $map, ".bsp"`, with the same result.

Thanks in advance.

PS: for reference, here's what a `maplist.txt`looks like:

```
zm_3dubka_v3
zm_4way_tunnel_v2
zm_abstractchode_pyramid2
zm_anotheruglyzmap_v1e
zm_app7e_betterbworld_JDfix_v3
zm_atix_helicopter_mini
zm_base_winter_beta3
zm_battleforce_panic_ua
zm_black_lion_macd_v8
zm_bunker_f57_v2
zm_burbsdelchode_b3
zm_choddarena_b12
zm_choddasnowpanic_b4
zm_citylife_V2b
zm_crazycity
zm_deep_thought_nv
zm_desert_fortress_v2
ZM_desprerados_a1
zm_doomlike_station_v2
zm_dust_arena_v1_final
zm_exhibit_night_2F
zm_facility_v1
zm_farm3_nav72
zm_firewall_samarkand
zm_fortress_b7
zm_ghs_flats
zm_gl33m4x_errata
zm_idm_hauntedhouse_v1
zm_industry_v2
zm_kruma_kakariko_village_006
zm_kruma_panic_004
zm_lila_off!ce_v4
zm_little_city_v5pf_fix
zm_moonlight_v3_pF
zm_moon_roflicious_pF_02
zm_moocbblechode_b2
zm_mountain_b2
zm_neko_abura_v2
zm_neko_athletic_park_v2
zm_novum_v3_JDfix
zm_ocx_orly_v4
zm_officeattack_b5a
zm_officerush_betav7
zm_officesspace_pfss
zm_omi_facility_pfv2
zm_penumbra_PF3
zm_raindance_ak_v2
zm_roflicious_pfcf2
zm_roy_abandoned_canals_new
zm_roy_barricade_factory
zm_roy_highway
zm_roy_industrial_complex
zm_roy_old_industrial_pF
zm_roy_the_ship_pf
zm_roy_zombieranch_night_b4
zm_survival_f2a
zm_temple_v3pf
zm_towers_v3
zm_tx_highschool_zkedit_v2
zm_unpanicv2_pF
zm_vc2_office_redone_b1
zm_wasteyard_beta3
zm_winterfun_b4a
zm_wtfhax_v6
zm_wtfhax_v6e
zm_wwt_twinsteel_v8
```

Comment: what os are you running this on?

Comment: @ennuikiller: Linux version 2.6.39-pf2 (...) (gcc version 4.4.5 (Gentoo 4.4.5 p1.2, pie-0.4.5) ) (...)

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce your problem, a few things to try:  open a new xterm and run it sometimes the settings on the xterm get mangled; is it possible you have 2 of the same process running twice?; make sure you have auto-flush turned on $| =1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd guess that the `maplist.txt` has non-unix line endings - probably dos - and as result you see what *looks like* prepending.

The problem is that the chomp() is only consuming one of the two line ending characters, leaving the carriage return behind.

You might find that if you set the [Perl special variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles) `$/` (input record seperator)  before opening the map list, that chomp then does the job - it will consume both line-ending characters.

```
$/ = qq{\r\n};
```

Another solution would be to convert the line endings in the file before processing, perhaps using [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html).

Comment: Bingo! I guess someone edited the file on Windows, or had it go through some Filezilla weirdness. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Filipe, Unlike martin clayton's solution, `open MAPLIST, "<:crlf", $maplist;` will work either the lines end with CRLF or just LF, and so will using `$map =~ s/\s+\z//;` instead of `chomp($map);`. I recommend the latter.